# How do I resolve my inability to login to WordPress dashboard?

Tags: login

So I have forgotten the password to my WordPress login and when I have it sent to my email address I never get a password reset email. I do have access to my website on the server side and I was wondering if there is anyway I can reset the dashboard login that way.

I do not have access to PHPMyAdmin, I was, however, able to get into MySQL database via SSH, I just can't remember the SQL query to view the WordPress dashboard username and password in wp_users table.

So this is how I added to functions.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Bootstrap to WordPress functions and definitions.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained
 *
 * @package Bootstrap to WordPress
 */
wp_set_password('new_password', 1);

if ( ! function_exists( 'bootstrap2wordpress_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
```

Comment: @Fayaz, I do not have access to PHPMyAdmin as I do not even remember the username and password of the database. It's been a long time since I have tried going into this website via backend.

Comment: Great, please edit your question and add that info. I'll respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can access the files with FTP or SSH, go to your WordPress `theme` directory and:

1. Go to the active theme
2. Open `functions.php` file.
3. Add the CODE below after `<?php` opening tag & upload the file:

   `wp_set_password( 'new_password', 1 );`
4. Now go to admin login page, typically `your-site.com/wp-admin/`
5. Log in with admin user (typically `admin`) and the temporary password `new_password`, as set in the CODE above.
6. Once you try to log in, the CODE above will simply reset your password and redirect to `wp-login.php` without actually going to admin panel.
7. At this point, edit `functions.php` again and remove the above CODE.
8. Now you will be able to log in to admin panel with `new_password` (or whatever password you've set in the CODE above).
9. Change your password from the admin panel (to something stronger) as an added security measure.

Comment: So I have tried admin and one other username I believe to be correct and it is not working for me.

Comment: Are there multiple themes? Is it possible you are editing `functions.php` from the wrong theme?

Comment: No multiple theme, I confirmed the username by displaying wp_users table.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw you updated to have access to mysql with SSH. Updating post based on this new info.

Comment: I marked my question as duplicate even though it kind of varied because the solution was the same but not through PHPMyAdmin, I did it via SSH.

Comment: Greetings Fayaz, the first time you helped me with this, I think I misunderstood the instructions. I used your instructions for a different situation and it worked. Come to think of it, your solution is awesome.